# Strange use of "were" with uncountable nouns

Tags: uncountable-nouns

In the sentence

> If aging **were** programmed, then...

**were** is used instead of **is** or **was** or **have been**. Why?

Comment: I think by "uncountable noun" you were referring to the *gerund* "aging".

Answer (score 10):

It is the **subjunctive mood**.  It is commonly known that "aging" is not programmed.  The second conditional here describes an *unlikely* situation in which "aging" ***is*** programmed.  So, the special form of "be" is used, "***were***".

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Victor Bazarov for pointing to the subjunctive mood. What I found in Wikipedia:

> The English subjunctive also occurs in counterfactual dependent
>   clauses, using a form of the verb that in the indicative would
>   indicate a time of action prior to the one implied by the subjunctive.
>   It is called the past subjunctive when referring counterfactually to
>   the present, and is called the pluperfect subjunctive when referring
>   counterfactually to the past. It occurs in that clauses following the
>   main-clause verb "wish" ("I wish that she were here now"; "I wish that
>   she had been here yesterday") and in if clauses expressing a condition
>   that does not or did not hold ("If she were here right now, ..."; "If
>   she had been here yesterday, ...").

Comment: The classic literary (theatrical) example: ["If I were a rich man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_I_Were_a_Rich_Man_(song)) (Fiddler on the Roof).

Comment: "would indicate a time of action prior" isn't really accurate.  Although there's some overlap in plural forms between present-subjunctive and past-indicative, the singular forms are frequently not the same.